# insert a line to a specific position in multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find

I am looking for a way to insert a line to a specific position in a file.

Kinda like this: [using sed](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/add-line-to-specific-position-in-file-linux.html)

But the problem is, i want to write the output into the same file where i get the input and i need to do it with more than one file.

sadly this does not work: `sed '3iline 3' input.txt > input.txt`

this would work: `sed '3iline 3' input.txt > tmp.txt && cat tmp.txt > input.txt`

but i doesn't work with find and exec anymore...

i hoped something like this would be possible:

```
find /usr/local/share/ -iname 'xyz.htm' -exec sed '19i<p>TEXT</p>' {} > {} \;
```

but it doesn't work like this, so i ended up writing a short script which worked. But it still bothers me, because i keep thinking it should be possible to do it short (maybe onliner) and easy.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, You need `-i` option.
Which will do the changes in original file. It is not require any other piping and redirection.

```
sed -i.bak '3iline 3' input.txt
```

This will take the backup of original file with .bak extension.

From `man sed` :

```
 -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
       edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```